# how to iterate all elements in an array when some of the elements are not defined?

Tags: arrays, bash

let's say:

```
$ a[0]=1
$ a[2]=2
```

then, when i do:

```
$ for b in "${a[@]}"; do echo $b; done
1
3
```

this is not what i want. since i skipped `a[1]`, it's not extending in a good sense. the "undefined" indices are skipped. i hope it can show an empty line for those, i.e.:

```
1

3
```

and even the length of the array is not quite expected:

```
$ echo ${#a[@]}
2
```

making it explicit won't work too:

```
$ unset a
$ declare -a a
$ a[0]=1
$ a[2]=2
$ for b in "${a[@]}"; do echo $b; done
1
2
$ echo ${#a[@]}
2
```

so any solution to this? this leads to the inconsistency among array length, index, and iteration.

bash version is not too old:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.0.28(1)-release
```

(i know it's a shell shock vulnerable version. my poor company.)

Comment: note: it's consistent. think in terms of keys, not indices.

Comment: Indeed. The expansion of `"${a[@]}"` is the values in the array. The expansion of `"${!a[@]}"` is the indices with values in the array. The expansion of `"${#a[@]}"` is the number of elements in the array. To get what you want you need to maintain a "max index" yourself.

Comment: em... i hardly think that's consistent. if it mixes up array and associative one, it loses consistency from the very beginning.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Don't confuse sparse arrays with associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is correct behavior for [sparse arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). However, if you want to iterate over a continuous range, because you know the start and end indices, you can simply do...

```
for (( i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++ )); do
    echo "${array[i]}"
done
```

Where `array[i]` is unset, the expansion will be the empty string, so you'll get what you asked for.

If you *don't* know the indices, you can get them using another array:

```
indices=( "${!array[@]}" )
firstIndex="${indices[0]}"
lastIndex="${indices[-1]}"
for (( i=firstIndex; i<=lastIndex; i++ )); do
    echo "${array[i]}"
done
```